# How to select also the following nodes after a selection?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm currently trying to also select the child edges and child nodes, when selecting a node. I tried the following function:

```
cy.on('tap', 'node', function(event){
    this.outgoers().select();
}
```

But it seems that i can't get it to work with 'tap'.
I also tried with 'select' which does work, but all the child nodes until the leaves are selected (which was expected).

Is there a way to implement this with 'tap' or can the recursive calls from 'select' be limited somehow?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Put your `.select()` call in a timeout.  It seems the default selection event is overriding your previous call.

Option 2: Bind to `'select'` so you know that the default selection event has already happened.